# Como posso obter os valores máximos e mínimos após aplicar o LOESS

Tags: r, ggplot2

Meus dados são trazidos de uma base e eu simplesmente aplico:

```
ggplot (data = df_postgres, aes (x = date_time, y = duracao)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "loess")
```

E obtenho a seguinte suavização:

[image: Suavização obtida]

Existe a possibilidade de obter os pontos máximos e mínimos da curva em azul?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pessoal. Das duas formas eu consegui obter o resultado que esperava.
Obrigada! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ggplot utiliza a função `loess` do base R. Você pode rodar o ajuste fora do comando gráfico e obter os valores usando `predict`:

```
set.seed(4)
dados <- data.frame(date_time = 1:20, duracao = rnorm(20))
dados.loess <- loess(duracao ~ date_time, data = dados)

summary(predict(dados.loess))
#    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
#-0.06347  0.15680  0.34110  0.35310  0.56030  0.74970
```

Confirmando o resultado, podemos adicionar as linhas no gráfico:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dados, aes (x = date_time, y = duracao)) +
  geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "loess") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = min(predict(dados.loess)))) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = max(predict(dados.loess))))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você sabe me dizer se tem como achar, também, para cada mudança da curva, o valor máximo e mínimo?

Comment: Você diz as mudanças de sinal da inclinação? Se sim, você vai precisar da derivada dos dados, que pode ser obtida com `diff`. Isso provavelmente seria mais apropriado em uma nova pergunta, mas dê uma olhada neste código. Use o da resposta e mude apenas onde tem 20 para 1000. `y <- predict(dados.loess);
plot(y, type = "l");
m <- abs(diff(y, 1));
match(sort(m), m)[1:10];
abline(v=c(6953, 2621))`.

Comment: Isso, cada mudança no sinal de inclinação, gostaria também de obter os pontos máximos e os pontos mínimos. Mas, nesse caso ele pega os máximos e mínimos dos pontos e não da curva.. Queria da curva que é gerada pelo LOESS também.

Comment: @Samara Sugiro que você faça uma nova pergunta para esse problema e inclua uma exemplo dos seus dados para facilitar o trabalho de quem for responder.

Comment: Está bem, obrigada.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Isso mesmo.. derivando os dados. Ficou assim: ` dados.frame <- data.frame(dados); plot(dados.frame); dados.loess <- loess(duracao ~date_time, data=dados.frame); xl <- with(dados.frame, seq(min(date_time),max(date_time), (max(date_time) - min(date_time))/1000)); y.predict <- predict(dados.loess, xl); lines(xl,y.predict); infl <- c(FALSE, diff(diff(y.predict)>0)!=0); points(xl[infl ], y.predict[infl ], col="Red", pch=19, cex=1.25) ` Muuuito obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa a função `stat_smooth` do `ggplot2`, ele realiza os seguintes passos:

Vou usar o banco de dados `mtcars`, mas você pode facilmente substituir pelo seu próprio.

```
modelo <- loess(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars) # ajusta o modelo  loess
mtcars$pred <- predict(modelo) # calcula as predicoes

ggplot (data = mtcars, aes (x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
 geom_line(aes(y = pred), colour = "blue") # plota as predicoes usando linha
```

Veja que este gráfico é igual ao gráfico feito usando:

```
ggplot (data = mtcars, aes (x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
 stat_smooth(method = "loess")
```

Portanto, para pegar o máximo valor da curva basta filtrar no seu data.frame:

```
mtcars[mtcars$pred == max(mtcars$pred), ]
```